# В условии не присваивается значение b к значению q

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел вычисляет сумму всех трехзначных чисел, кратных 3 и оканчивающихся на 2. Программа получает на вход натуральные числа, количество введённых чисел неизвестно, последовательность чисел заканчивается числом 0 (0 – признак окончания ввода, не входит в последовательность). Количество чисел не превышает 1000. Введённые числа не превышают 30 000.
Программа должна вывести два значения в двух строках.
Первое значение: сумму всех трехзначных чисел, кратных 3 и оканчивающихся на 2, или вывести «NO», если таких чисел нет.
Второе число: если есть хотя бы одно трёхзначное число кратное 3 и оканчивающиеся на 2, программа должна вывести второе число - максимальное число среди всех введенных трехзначных чисел кратных 3 и оканчивающихся на 2. Если выведено «NO», то вывести вторым числом минимальное число среди всех введенных чисел в последовательности.

```
Sample Input 2:

172
16
322
160
0
Sample Output 2:

NO
16
```

```
q=int(input())
w=0
b=30001
while q!=0:
    if q!=0 and q % 10 == 2  and q % 3 == 0 :
        w=w+q
        a=q
        if b>q:
            b=q
    q=int(input())
if w!=0:
        print(w)
        print(a) 
else:
    print('NO')
    print(b)
```

после того как я ввожу числа выводится следующее:

```
NO
30001
```

Comment: Поправлю что `if` это не функция а условие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res1 = 0
max_ = -1
min_ = 30001
while True:
    q = int(input())
    if q == 0:
        break
    if q < min_:
        min_ = q
    if 100 <= q <= 999 and q % 6 == 0 :
        res1 += q
        if q > max_:
            max_ = q

print(res1 if res1 > 0 else "NO")
print(max_ if res1 > 0 else min_)
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас много мелких огрехов. Должно быть примерно так

```
q=int(input())
w = 0
# задавать будущему минимуму надо больше, чем максимально возможное значение, 
# а максимуму в вашем случае можно задать 0
max = 0
min = 30001
while q!=0:
    # минимум на всякий случай надо всегда собрать
    if min > q :
        min = q
    # с нулем сравнивать не надо - while уже проверил
    if q % 10 == 2  and q % 3 == 0 :
        w += 1
        # а максимум только для нужных чисел. Обратите внимание на то, как сравнивается
        if max < q:
            max = q
    q=int(input())
if w!=0:
    print(w)
    print(max) 
else:
    print('NO')
    print(min)
```

или так

```
ilist = []
q=int(input())
while q != 0 :
    ilist.append(q)
    q=int(input())  

temp  = [q for q in ilist if q % 10 == 2  and q % 3 == 0]

if len(temp):
    print(len(temp))
    print(max(temp)) 
else:
    print('NO')
    print(min(ilist))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = '2 3 4 702 672 701 102 0 822'.split()  # input().split()
lst = lst[:lst.index('0')]
ilst = list(map(int, lst))
assert (len(lst) <= 1000) and not any((a > 30000) for a in ilst)
r = [i for (a, i) in (zip(lst, ilst)) if ((len(a) == 3) and (not (i % 3)) and (a[-1] == '2'))]  # ['702', '672', '102']
if r:
    print(sum(r))
    print(max(ilst))
else:
    print('NO')
    print(min(ilst))
```